# Creation of macros for a part of commutative diagram

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I am using tikz-cd for drawing commutative diagrams. Most of them are just exact triangles which are written as a sequence like
`a -> b -> c -> a[1]`
or two or three of them as rows, connected with 4 separate named arrows. I think that if it is possible to write them like

```
\start{something}
\ExactTriangle{a, b, c} \\
\ExactTriangle{a, b, c} \\
\ExactTriangle{a, b, c} \\
\Morphism{1, 2}{x, y, z} 
\Morphism{2, 3}{x', y', z'}
\end{something}
```

instead of

```
\[
\begin{tikzcd} 
    a \arrow[r] \arrow[d, "x"] & b \arrow[r] \arrow[d, "y"] & c \arrow[r] \arrow[d, "z"] & a[1] \arrow[d, "x{[1]}"] \\
    a \arrow[r] \arrow[d, "x'"] & b \arrow[r] \arrow[d, "y'"] & c \arrow[r] \arrow[d, "z'"] & a[1] \arrow[d, "x'{[1]}"] \\
    a \arrow[r] & b \arrow[r]  & c \arrow[r] & a[1]  \\
\end{tikzcd}
\]
```

and get result like:
[image]
It would increase both their readability and speed of creation/fixing compared to reading and writing down all these `\arrow`s. But most similar questions which i read are answered with advice to use tikz-cd environment wrapped into some command, and I got vague impression that inside tikz environment there is no way to define custom commands like this. So the question is: Is it possible to do such thing with tikz-cd, is there some other package that allows doing things like this or is there a way that could be compared with readability and flexibility to this potential one.

Comment: Could you please show exactly to what this should be translated?

Comment: Can you show some tikz-cd code that does what you need but is in your opinion "long" and "inelegant"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that using Ti*k*Z and `\pic`s you can achieve a close enough code as the one in your example.

Like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\tikzset
{%
  pics/ExactTriangle/.style n args={3}{
      code={%
        \node[inner sep=1pt] (-4) at (4.5,0) {\strut$a[1]$};
        \foreach[count=\ii]\i in {#1,#2,#3}
          \node[inner sep=1pt] (-\ii) at (1.5*\ii-1.5,0) {\strut$\i$};
        \foreach\i in {1,2,3}
        {
          \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\i+1}
          \draw[-latex] (-\i.east) -- (-\j.west);
        }
    }},
  pics/Morphism/.style n args={5}{
      code={%
        \foreach[count=\ii]\i in {#3,#4,#5}
          \draw[-latex] (#1-\ii) -- (#2-\ii) node[midway,right] {\strut$\i$};
        \draw  [-latex] (#1-4)   -- (#2-4)   node[midway,right] {\strut$#3[1]$};
      }},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=-1cm]
  \pic (1) at (0,0)   {ExactTriangle={a}{b}{c}};
  \pic (2) at (0,1.5) {ExactTriangle={a}{b}{c}};
  \pic (3) at (0,3)   {ExactTriangle={a}{b}{c}};
  \pic {Morphism={1}{2}{x}{y}{z}};
  \pic {Morphism={2}{3}{x'}{y'}{z'}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]